# How to listen for all page loads and refreshes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am attempting to check for a cookie's existence whenever any kind of HTTP-related event occurs -- like the user refreshes a page or goes from one page to the next. If the cookie is found, a timer is activated starting from the cookie's value.

I tried `on("page:load")`, but it's not behaving like I thought it would. Is `page:load` indeed the proper listener, or is there a more general way of encompassing all events after which global variables would be reset? Relevant code:

```
$(document).on("page:load",function(){
    if(isCookie('start_time') || $start_time) {
        timerRunningDisplay();
        activateTimer();            
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use `$(document).ready(function(){});` instead. That will definitely fire when a page is loaded or refreshed. Then it's just a matter of making sure you're setting a referring to the cookie correctly, and you're golden.

So:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(isCookie('start_time') || $start_time) {
        timerRunningDisplay();
        activateTimer();            
    }
});
```

Comment: We got a winner. Thanks James.